# Laravel migration self referencing foreign key auto increments with primary key

Tags: laravel

Firstly, my English very bad. Sorry about that.

I have a foreign key in curricula table like:

```
        Schema::create('curricula', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id("curriculum_id");
            $table->string("subject")->nullable();
            $table->string("desc")->nullable();
            $table->string("curriculum_type")->nullable();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('curriculum_state_id');
            $table->boolean("active")->nullable();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('faculty_id')->nullable();
            $table->foreign('faculty_id')->references('table_line_id')->on('table_lines')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->softDeletesTz($column = 'deleted_at', $precision = 0);
            $table->timestamps();

        });
        Schema::table('curricula',function(Blueprint $table){
            $table->foreign('curriculum_state_id')->on('curricula')->references('curriculum_id');
        });
```

I want to auto increments foreign key (curriculum_state_id) like primary key (curriculum_id)
How I can solve that. Thank you!

//curriculum_state_id self referencing foreign key

Comment: You can only have one auto increment per table. Why don't you use `curriculum_id` ?

Answer (score 0):

In your question is

```
    Schema::create('curricula', function (Blueprint $table) {
        ...
        $table->$table->bigIncrements('curriculum_state_id')->unsigned();
        ...
    });
```

In documentation from: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/migrations#column-method-bigIncrements

but foreign key can't be auto increments you can contact me privately and I can give you a private advice. Good luck :)